# Sticky footer breaks layout on resize

Tags: css

I am using the sticky footer script from ([Ryan Fait website](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/)) which works great, but the moment I resize my browser (or minimize it) the footer pushes to the top over other text, and breaks completely.

I have a live example at ([sports and events website](http://www.sportsandevents.co.za))

Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: not sure what your problem is, but this one has always worked for me http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: Hey @ScottSimpson, I use to use that one but found it creates a 4px or odd overflow, so there is always a scroll bar on the right hand side irrespective what I do.

Comment: That is odd -- but these devices are rather brittle. One slight mistake and they break. If I were having this issue, I would create a layout ONLY with the sticky footer code and ensure that sticky footer was working by adding and removing extra code via the DOM inspector. THEN -- add in MY custom code from my site in the appropriate spaces in the SF framework.

Comment: I am a tad confused. I've looked at your website and it appears you followed my suggestion and added the `clear:both` to `#footer, .push` which was the css you had not added in from the Ryan Fait method you are using. So I was just wondering why you didn't accept my answer?

Comment: I added both your clear: both and overflow: hidden as suggested by @Rohit Azad. Initially the clear: both did not work and it only worked with the combination of the 2

Comment: I see. Well I can assure you, that you don't need `overflow:hidden` on `#wrapper`. If it was necessary it would have been included as part of Ryan Fait's code. Using developer tools I've disabled it and the `clear:both` still works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your **ID** `#mian_content :overflow:hidden;`

**as like this**

```
#main_content {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Result is this**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `clear:both` to your `#footer, .push` rule. Add in the css as below and it will work.

```
#footer, .push {
    height: 202px;
    clear: both; /* add this */
}
```